# Android Realm filter objects that have one items in their lists

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I have an object called Offer that has a field, that is a list of RealmInts called regions. I want to filter only those offers that in their lists have a specific region id, let's say 1. How can I achieve this ?

For counting those offers I've used this code but I hope there is something more effective:

```
int result = 0;
RealmResults<Offer> offers = offerQuery.findAll();
for (Offer o : offers) {
    if (o.getRegions().contains(new RealmInt(selectedLocation))) {
            result++;
       }
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: Have you considered storing your `RealmList<RealmInt>` as a single String field? If it's formatted as `,1,4,6,334,1,` then you could do a `contains("regions", "," + number + ",").count()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible as I am downloadign data from server in this specific form